# How to access data of XML child element, the data is recieved from external api in WordPress PHP?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I'm new to php so please ignore my silly mistakes.
My retrieved XML data looks like this

```
    <? xmlversion = "1.0"encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<ResponseDS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Code>00</Code>
    <InternalDescription />
    <Description />
    <DS>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="modified">
                    <FullName>Prof. Phil Brown</FullName>
                    </Table>
                    </NewDataSet>
                    </diffgr:diffgram>
                    </DS>
                    </ResponseDS>
```

I want to access FullName and print.

I tried

```
$xml = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml));
    $data = json_decode($json);
      $name = $data->object->DS->diffgram->NewDataSet->Table->FullName;
        echo"<h2>$name</h2>";
```

also tried foreach loop to traverse through but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Share your full XML

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$reponseXML = '<? xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResponseDS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <Code>00</Code>
    <InternalDescription />
    <Description />
    <DS>
        <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="modified">
                    <FullName>Prof. Phil Brown</FullName>
                    </Table>
                    </NewDataSet>
                    </diffgr:diffgram>
                    </DS>
                    </ResponseDS>'
    
    $responseObj = simplexml_load_string($reponseXML);
    
    $fullName = $responseObj -> DS -> diffgram -> NewDataSet -> Table -> FullName
```

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Right. Replace the wrapping double quotes ("") with single quotes ('')